# How to reduce a stream of Futures in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

Assuming that I have given a `Stream` of `Futures`, which I want to reduce by invoking the `Stream#reduce` method.
But I don't want to reduce the `Futures` itself, but the result of the `Future` (`Future#get`).
The problem is, that the [get method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) may throw an `ExecutionException` and does not provide a result in this case.

This is the reason why

```
Stream<Future<Integer>> stream = ...;
BinaryOperator<Integer> sum = (i1, i2) -> i1 + i2;  
stream.map(future -> future.get())
      .reduce(sum); // does not work, get needs to handle exceptions!
```

So, I have to catch the exceptions:

```
stream.map(future -> {
    Integer i = null;
    try {
        i = future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {}
    return i;
}).reduce(sum);
```

But in this approach, I may get troubles because `null` values may appear.

So, to get rid of these, I would have to filter those out, where a `ExecutionException` appeared:

```
stream.filter(future -> {
    Integer i = null;
    try {
        i = future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    }
    return i != null;
})
.map(future -> {
    Integer i = null;
    try {
        i = future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    }
    return i;
}).reduce(sum);
```

I think, this code would work.. But I don't want to believe, that this is the only and the smartest way to reduce Futures.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I think an equally important question is *why would you leave the exceptionally completed futures unhandled?*

Comment: Not sure but maybe considering using the fork/join framework in your case could be an option? That would likely imply rethinking a significant part of your code though.

Comment: I get the Futures after submitting multiple computations with the help of an `ExecutorService`. I know, that this computations could not lead to an `Exception`, so I don't have to handle them.

Comment: I would suggest to use `CompletedFuture` instaed of `Future` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Comment: A pure stream solution would be `.flatMap(future -> { try { return Stream.of(future.get()); } catch(<Exceptions>) { return Stream.empty(); })`. That said I think there are better solutions using the future api as suggested by Deadpool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extract the value from the future first, and then filter out null:

```
Integer result = stream
    .map(future -> {
        try {
          return future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        }
        return null; })
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .reduce(sum)
    .orElse(0);
```

Comment: This one is a good solution! But wouldn't it be nicer if `Future` would have a method like `isExceptionOccured` or something like that, or am I wrong?

Comment: @mrbela Yeah, but in this case what would return `Future.get()` in case of exception ?

Comment: The actual behavior could stay the same, throw an exception in `Future.get()`, but with such a method, it would be much easier to filter a Future stream.. And I am sure there would be much more advantages in many other situations.

Comment: No sure to see the benefit... you would still need to surround the `get()` method with try-catch.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to simplify it could be:

```
void reduceImpl(Stream<Future<Integer>> stream) {
    Optional<Integer> integerOptional = stream
            .map(this::transform)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .reduce(Integer::sum);
}

private Integer transform(Future<Integer> future) {
    try {
        return future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        return null; // should ideally be handled properly
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using `flatMap`:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<Future<Integer>> yourStream = null;

        int sum = yourStream.flatMap(YourClass::unpack)
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .sum()
            .orElse(0);
    }

    public static <T> Stream<T> unpack(Future<T> future) {
        try {
            return Stream.of(future.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return Stream.empty();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            return Stream.empty();
        }
    }
```